# What is the difference between "se ven afectados" and "están afectados"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, verbo-pronominal, voz-pasiva, oraciones-pasivas-reflejas

I've noticed that "**se ven afectados**" and "**están afectados**" are translated as "are affected."  Some examples:

**se ven afectados**

> [Muchos ejemplares **se ven afectados** por las crecientes amenazas
> provocadas por la acción humana.](https://elpais.com/elpais/2017/10/17/album/1508240799_444335.html)
>
> *Many specimens **are affected** by the growing threats caused by human action.*
>
> [Al considerar que quienes **se ven afectados** por esos escándalos de
> corrupción son los mexicanos, ...](https://www.eleconomista.com.mx/politica/Quieren-investigar-sobre-el-caso-Odebrecht-20200902-0115.html)
>
> *Considering that those who **are affected** by these corruption scandals are the Mexicans, ...*
>
> [¿Cómo **se ven afectados** por la pandemia las personas en países
> devastados por el conflicto como Yemen, Sudán del Sur y Siria?](https://www.lanacion.com.ar/el-mundo/cinco-maneras-coronavirus-empeorara-situacion-personas-vulnerables-nid2366702)
>
> *How **are** people in conflict-torn countries like Yemen, South Sudan and Syria **affected** by the pandemic?*

**están afectados**

> [Entre el 10% y el 15% de los escolares de primaria y secundaria
> españoles **están afectados** de dislexia.](https://elpais.com/diario/1998/10/13/sociedad/908229621_850215.html)
>
> *Between 10% and 15% of Spanish primary and secondary school students **are affected** by dyslexia.*
>
> [Se considera que la población dentro de un inmueble está en peligro
> cuando el 20% de los habitantes **están afectados**.](https://www.eleconomista.com.mx/arteseideas/Por-que-tu-oficina-puede-enfermarte-20161128-0030.html)
>
> *The population within a building is considered to be in danger when 20% of the inhabitants **are affected**.*
>
> [«Si los cangrejos ya **están afectados**, ...](https://cnnespanol.cnn.com/2020/01/28/el-oceano-pacifico-es-tan-acido-que-esta-disolviendo-los-caparazones-de-estos-cangrejos/)
>
> *"If the crabs **are** already **affected**, ...*

Is there any reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: I think there's not a rule on when to choose one or another, and I think it is more related on the way the writer or speaker really understand or get sense to its own words. But that's my opinion and maybe I could be wrong.

Comment: There is no rule per se. It's a feeling about how the utterance would sound. By the way, this applies to many se + verb versus estar + verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of [ver](https://dle.rae.es/ver) on DLE:

> 17. prnl. Hallarse en algún lugar, estado o situación. *Verse allí. Verse pobre, abatido, agasajado.*

does not help much to distinguish it "verse" from "estar" or "ser". The difference is quite small.

The way I see it, however, is that "verse" with this meaning is somewhat equivalent to the English "find oneself", i.e., it conveys a meaning of something partially **unexpected and unavoidable**, or at least **new**. This nuance is clear in your examples of "verse afectado", which are about "growing threats", "corruption scandals", and "the pandemic": all unexpected and unavoidable events.

On the other hand, "estar" is much more general and is valid in all cases. In particular, when talking about a state that has already lasted for a long time, it would be very strange to use "verse afectado", because the state is no longer new or unexpected:

> Entre el 10% y el 15% de los escolares de primaria y secundaria españoles <del>se ven</del> están afectados de dislexia.

in the same way as you would not say

- Between 10% and 15% of Spanish primary and secondary school students <del>find themselves</del> affected by dyslexia.

Similarly, in the case of the crabs, the state is **already** present (because of the word "ya"), so you can say

- Si los cangrejos ya **están afectados**...

or

- Si los cangrejos ya **se han visto afectados**...

in past tense (actually present perfect), but you would not say

- Si los cangrejos ya <del>se ven afectados</del>...

Comment: What a great answer and with such great examples, too.  Your comments actually help me understand the difference more than I was expecting!  As a cheeky sort of practical application, can I then say in Spanish, _¡Me veo afectado por tu comentario!_?

Comment: @LisaBeck you could say that if you are a male. If you are a female, you would say "me veo afectada por tu comentario". Another option is "Tu comentario me ha afectado". Though when saying (in Spanish) that a comment has affected you, it is usually interpreted as meaning that the comment had a somewhat strong emotional effect on you. If you do not want the "emotional" connotation, you can of course say "Tu comentario me ha ayudado".

Comment: One of the best, most useful comments I've ever read.  Thank you for adding it!